# Polymer Correct way to make sidemenu with submenu with icons

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

What is correct way to make sidemenu using paper-menu with list of items that use icons on the left and have submenus which too have icons.

```
<paper-menu>
 <paper-submenu>
  <paper-icon-item> 
   <iron-icon icon="inbox" item-icon></iron-icon> 
   Inbox
  </paper-icon-item>
  <paper-menu class="menu-content">
  <paper-icon-item> 
   <iron-icon icon="inbox" item-icon></iron-icon> 
   Submenu 1
  </paper-icon-item>
  <paper-icon-item> 
   <iron-icon icon="inbox" item-icon></iron-icon> 
   Submenu 2
  </paper-icon-item>
  <paper-icon-item> 
   <iron-icon icon="inbox" item-icon></iron-icon> 
   Submenu 3
  </paper-icon-item>
  </paper-menu>
 </paper-submenu>
 <paper-icon-item> 
  <iron-icon icon="inbox" item-icon></iron-icon> 
  Second menu
 </paper-icon-item>
</paper-menu>
```

Made this with Polymer Documentation and it is not working.

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail on what is not working?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37454080/sidemenu-with-submenu-and-all-with-icons

Answer (score 1):

Following the [`<paper-submenu>` docs](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-menu?active=paper-submenu), nested menus normally follow this pattern, where each expandable submenu has:

- a `paper-item` (or equivalent) of class **`menu-trigger`**, which serves as the submenu's header
- a `paper-menu` of class **`menu-content`**, which serves as the submenu's item container

```
<paper-menu>
  <paper-submenu>
    <paper-item class="menu-trigger">
      Heading 1
    </paper-item>
    <paper-menu class="menu-content">
      ...
    </paper-menu>
  </paper-submenu>
</paper-menu>
```

It looks like your example was missing the `menu-trigger` class on your header items (i.e., "Inbox" and "Second menu").

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.2.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="paper-menu/paper-menu.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-menu/paper-submenu.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-item/paper-icon-item.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-icon/iron-icon.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
</head>
<body>
  <style>
    .menu-trigger {
      color: blue;
    }
  </style>
  <paper-menu>
    <paper-submenu>
      <paper-icon-item class="menu-trigger">
        <iron-icon icon="inbox" item-icon></iron-icon> 
        Inbox
      </paper-icon-item>
      <paper-menu class="menu-content">
        <paper-icon-item> 
          <iron-icon icon="inbox" item-icon></iron-icon> 
          Submenu 1
        </paper-icon-item>
        <paper-icon-item> 
        <iron-icon icon="inbox" item-icon></iron-icon> 
          Submenu 2
          </paper-icon-item>
        <paper-icon-item> 
          <iron-icon icon="inbox" item-icon></iron-icon> 
          Submenu 3
        </paper-icon-item>
      </paper-menu>
    </paper-submenu>

    <paper-submenu>
      <paper-icon-item class="menu-trigger"> 
        <iron-icon icon="inbox" item-icon></iron-icon> 
        Second menu
      </paper-icon-item>
      <paper-menu class="menu-content">
        <paper-icon-item> 
          <iron-icon icon="inbox" item-icon></iron-icon> 
          Submenu 1
        </paper-icon-item>
        <paper-icon-item> 
        <iron-icon icon="inbox" item-icon></iron-icon> 
          Submenu 2
          </paper-icon-item>
        <paper-icon-item> 
          <iron-icon icon="inbox" item-icon></iron-icon> 
          Submenu 3
        </paper-icon-item>
      </paper-menu>
    </paper-submenu>
  </paper-menu>
</body>
```

<sup>[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/valuve/edit?html,output)</sup>